# How can I add a post insert hook to Solr?

Tags: solr, hook, solr4

I am using Solr 5.3.1 and would like to run some code whenever a new document is inserted into Solr.

I am aware of the `<listener>` element in solrconfig.xml, however this does not provide a mechanism (as far as I can tell) to pass the new document, or its ID, to the listener code.

Do I need to create my own *UpdateRequestHandler*?

Comment: It might be more clear, easier and more feature-rich to hook into the source of the update (your application), instead of the Solr server.

Comment: I agree, sadly the source is a OTS product that only offers the ability to index direct to Solr.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook the insertion of documents both before and after they're added through the [StatelessScriptUpdateProcessor](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html) which allows you to write a JavaScript that has access to all the fields of the document. There's an example at the [Script Update Processor wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor#JavaScript):

```
function processAdd(cmd) {
    doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
    id = doc.getFieldValue("id");
```

This example should also be included as one of the example cores in the current bundle.